# Asp.net MVC Ajax iteration

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

I am returning an object to my view using `$.getJSON`.  The object contains a number of Lists, that I need to iterate over.  How can this be done?  My code so far is:

```
$.getJSON("/Home/GetData",
        function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (index) {
                //access data here for each list in object?
            });
        });
```

Thanks.

Comment: This code seems fine... What would you like to accomplish? Do you need to iterate over items of all lists or over lists...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking here, you're getting back JSON object of this form:

```
// result
{
    people: [{...}, {...}, ... , {...}],
    places: [{...}, {...}, ... , {...}],
    ...
}
```

You should first iterate over your returned JSON object and then iterate over each list's items individually. Something along these lines:

```
$.getJSON("/Home/GetData", function (data) {
    // iterate over lists in an object
    for(var list in data)
    {
        // list variable holds the name of the list (ie. "people")
        // iterate over list items
        $.each(data[list], function (index) {
            // do something with this list item
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When using $.each, the signature is:

```
$.each(data, function (index, item) {
    //access data here for each list in object?
});
```

So the item can be accessed directly.  Also, I think a list should be pushed up as an array, so you can have any number of $.each statements as you need.  The next inner array would be available via:

```
$.each(item.SubList, function(si, sitem) {

});
```

If you post the data structure pushed, we could help more.  Also, the object you are returning, is it an anonymous class or strongly-typed?  Are you returning a JsonResult?

HTH.

Comment: no need to access current item through `item`. You can easily just use `this`.